# OnItemClickListener() in ListView is not working

Tags: android, listview, onclick, simplecursoradapter

This is the code that I made to populate a `ListView` with a `SimpleCursorAdapter`. But I am not able to implement the `onClick` listener in this code.  Actually the code is working properly without errors, but I am not getting any output on clicking an item...

```
public class Senditems extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener
{
    TextView output;
    DataHelper dh;
    ListView empListView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sendto);

        Table1 employeeTable = new Table1(this);    
        employeeTable.open();
        Cursor c = employeeTable.fetchAllEmployee();
        if (c!= null)
        {
            SimpleCursorAdapter adapter2 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.sendto,c, 
                new String[] {c.getColumnName(1),c.getColumnName(2)}, 
                new int[] {R.id.EmployeeName, R.id.EmployeeDesignation});
            empListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.Employee);
            empListView.setAdapter(adapter2);
            empListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)                
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "1 item clicked ",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
       }

       employeeTable.close();
    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }
}
```

Comment: did u solve problem? what kind of UI elements u had in a sendto layout? Button, ImageButton, CheckBox maybe?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like `android:inputType` might lead to this problem, even if you use a `TextView`. I had the same issue and removing the attribute `android:inputType` from the `TextView`s fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hi  varada i am working with your code i impliment your code it is working fine the following change made in your code

1. Please provide _id primary key field in yor table.
2. and use this code it is working fine and give the position in toast
   on item click

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener
   {
       TextView output;
       ListView empListView;

       @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
       {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

           SimpleCursorAdapter adapter2=null;
           try {
               Table1 employeeTable = new Table1(this);    
               employeeTable.open();
               try {
                    // employeeTable.insert("Ankit", "Name");
               } catch (Exception e) {
                   // TODO: handle exception
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }



               Cursor c = employeeTable.fetchAllEmployee();
               if (c!= null)
               {
                    adapter2 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                       R.layout.sendto,c, 
                       new String[] {c.getColumnName(1),c.getColumnName(2)}, 
                       new int[] {R.id.EmployeeName, R.id.EmployeeDesignation});

              }



              employeeTable.close();
           } catch (Exception e) {
               // TODO: handle exception
               e.printStackTrace();

           }
           empListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.Employee);
           empListView.setAdapter(adapter2);
           empListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
               public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)                
               {
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "position"+position,  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
           });
       }

       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) 
       {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
       }
   }``
   ```

   3-sendto.xml

   ```
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/EmployeeName"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="TextView" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/EmployeeDesignation"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="TextView" />
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue. I changed it to `OnClickListner`.

```
rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //give ur code here
    }
});
```

here `rowView` corresponds to the row within the `ListView`.

Comment: If I add OnClickListener to it the application is showing an error while running that it has stopped unexpectedly, Please try again..

Answer (score 0):

If you are implementing the `OnItemClickListener` and `onItemClick` is auto generated you should write the actions inside it:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (view.equals(empListView))
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"1 item clicked ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }  
}
```

and also include `empListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);`

Comment: Thanks for your help.. But in that case also I didnt get any output. I can see the listview populated but onclick is not working. I added the above code Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"1 item clicked ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); after the commend // TODO Auto-generated method stub. Then added  empListView.setOnItemClickListener(this); on the onCreate method. Could you please suggest an example of this issue that is resolved?

Comment: Then i am sure you having some focusable items like checkbox, button or something . Do you?

Comment: I have 2 textviews on that. I mean I am populating the textviews in a listview from the database. On the above code R.id.EmployeeName, R.id.EmployeeDesignation are two textviews. In that case hat should be done to implement the onclick event?

Answer (score 0):

Its happens when actual view is not taking focus due to others view in your row file, check I already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14972690/646806), may be it's helps.