# Listview doesn't respond to OnItemClickListener after first few items

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

I have a listview in my android app which is showing data from downloading & parsing a json. In this listview, OnItemClickListener is not responding after first five or six items.Can anybody please tell me what is my problem ?

Here is my code for listview :

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {                   
                String s = BookJsonParser.ids[arg2];
                String bookDetailUrl =  url + s;
                DownloadBookDetail downloadTaskbookDetail = new DownloadBookDetail();
                downloadTaskbookDetail.execute(bookDetailUrl);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.printStackTrace(););
            }
        }

    });
```

DownloadBookDetail is an asyncTask where Json String is downloading in it's doInBackGround method & it is opening another asyncTask in it's onPostExecute method. 
In 2nd asyncTask, I am parsing json in doInBackground method & loading the listview with a adapter in onPostExecute method. 
Second asyncTask's code :

```
    /** AsyncTask to parse json data and load ListView */
private class ListViewLoaderTask extends
        AsyncTask<String, Void, SimpleAdapter> {

    JSONObject jObject;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(BookActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Listing New Books...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    // Doing the parsing of xml data in a non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected SimpleAdapter doInBackground(String... strJson) {
        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(strJson[0]);
            BookJsonParser countryJsonParser = new BookJsonParser();
            countryJsonParser.parse(jObject);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("JSON Exception1", e.toString());
        }

        // Instantiating json parser class
        BookJsonParser countryJsonParser = new BookJsonParser();

        // A list object to store the parsed countries list
        List<HashMap<String, Object>> countries = null;

        try {
            // Getting the parsed data as a List construct
            countries = countryJsonParser.parse(jObject);
            System.out.println(countries.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
        }

        // Keys used in Hashmap
        String[] from = { "country", "flag", "author" };

        // Ids of views in listview_layout
        int[] to = { R.id.tv_bookName, R.id.list_image, R.id.tv_bookAuthor };

        // /////////
        /*
         * for (int i = 0; i < BookJsonParser.ids.length; i++) {
         * System.out.println(BookJsonParser.ids[i]); }
         */

        // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
        // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(),
                countries, R.layout.item_lv_layout, from, to);

        return adapter;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seem your view is not taking focus in listview.It's the issue of view when you click the list row, it is always the capture other view event. apply below property to your main layout in row file and let me know whether its works or not?

`android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`

Answer (score 0):

RobinHood, thanks for the answer, it helps me.

In my case, I used custom view for ContactsCursorAdapter with Button. If Button is Invisible or Gone - everything works fine, but if i set it as Visible, then setOnItemClickListener on the ListView didn't work.

Comment: Robinhoods answer fixed it for me too.